# How do I use HTML5 Boilerplate without using the htaccess on an Apache server?

Tags: html, .htaccess, html5boilerplate

My client will not let me have access to the htaccess file on the server I'm hosting his new website on because of concerns about the security of his e-commerce store. How do I use HTML5 Boilerplate WITHOUT using the htaccess file?

I am very very new to all of this so please explain as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess` provides fine-tuning of your server settings. It is not necessary, but recommended. If your hosting don't allow you to use `.htaccess`, just don't use it.

Comment: Well, I loaded up the entire boilerplate on my server and nothing is working - locally or on my remote server. I assumed it had something to do with the htaccess file, but I guess I am wrong. Hmm. Thanks.

Comment: I don't need a server config at all? When I go to initializr.com, which is just customized H5BP, one of the options is server config.

Comment: @imakeitpretty You may need it for some concrete task, but it's not necessary for deploying your website, using `BoilerPlate`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the htaccess. The only thing you might need are the mime types. The otehr stuff is optional.